# Calling SharePoint (2013) Web Service through browser

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I am pretty sure you can return data by passing in argument to an SP service through a browser, firefox in my case. I am trying to use the GetGroupCollectionFromUser from the UserGroup.asmx service.

I think the url should be along the lines of h.ttp://site/mysitecollection/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx?op=GetGroupCollectionFromUser&query=domain/user

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and got error(below) with authentication.

**The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request**

You can to use REST services from browser. For your task use this url `http://mysharepoint2013portal/_api/site/rootweb/GetUserById(usrID)/groups`

Hope it help to you.